# MySqlDataReader method for getting boolean values

Tags: asp.net, mysql, mysqldatareader

I'm retrieving data from a MySQL table and displaying it on a webpage using MySqlDataReader and .NET (C#), with no trouble retrieving simple text data, but I'm having trouble retrieving data from a boolean column, as the possible values are either "1" or "*null*" and GetBoolean() doesn't work in this instance.

I'm using the GetString() and GetDateTime() methods for the aforementioned columns (e.g. myReader.GetString("name") & myReader.GetDateTime("startDate")), is there a similar method for retrieving the boolean values when they are label as either "1" or "*null*"?

Comment: try  `myreader["boolcl"] != null ? myreader.GetBoolean("boolcl") : false;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `IsDBNull()` in your code:

```
if(myReader.IsDBNull("BooleanColumnName") == true)
{
    // column contains a null value
    // handle null as you see fit
}
else
{
    var columnValue = myReader.GetBoolean("BooleanColumnName");
    if(columnValue == true)
    {
        // column value is "true"
    }
    else
    {
        // column value is "false"
    }
}
```